# I am trying to style the thumb of a range input but the webkit doesn't work

Tags: html, css, sass

Well I am trying to style a range thumb in chrome but the my code just doesn't work in any way and I don't know why:

```
html 
<input type="range" min="0" max="38" value="20" class="slider" id="slider">
```

```
sass:
&::-webkit-slider-thumb
      background-color: #000000
      clip-path: polygon(0 46%, 100% 45%, 100% 60%, 0 61%)
      height: 100%
      width: 50%
      padding: 0
      opacity: 0.8
      &:hover
        opacity: 1
```

This is the jfidle whit all the code https://jsfiddle.net/81x7v4tn/
open in in chrome to see the problem

Comment: You most add hover state on your range input not on slider-thumb

Comment: can you create a fiddle of it?

Comment: Created @SaurabhLP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was that you haven't eliminated the default appearance of the slider thumb. So no custom style would be implemented if the default appearance is set.

**Change done to SASS:**

```
&::-webkit-slider-thumb
      -webkit-appearance: none
      appearance: none
      background-color: #000000
      //clip-path: polygon(0 46%, 100% 45%, 100% 60%, 0 61%)
      height: 100%
      width: 50%
      padding: 0
      cursor: pointer
      opacity: 1
```

**Working fiddle:-** https://jsfiddle.net/5pe42ron/

I hope that works for you.

Thanks